# How to make a discord.js eval command that outputs like this

Tags: javascript, discord.js, eval

So I'm working on my bot and all that, and I noticed that someone else in the server has a bot that, when you use the eval command, puts the input and output in an embed, and the output looks like this for a setActivity eval thing. How would I go about implementing this into my code, if possible, or what would I do for that?

```
ClientPresence {
  userID: null,
  guild: null,
  status: 'online',
  activities: [Array],
  clientStatus: null
}
```

Here is my current code -

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix } = require('./../../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: 'eval',
    description: 'eval a bit of code',
    async execute (client, message, args) {
        if (message.author.id !== "559200051629654026") return;
        if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "eval")) {
            var result = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
            let evaled = eval(result);
            const evalEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .addFields(
                    { name: '**Input:**', value: `\`\`\`js\n${args}\`\`\``, inline: false },
                    { name: '**Output:**', value: `\`\`\`js\n${evaled}\`\`\``, inline: false }
                )
            message.channel.send(evalEmbed)
        }
    },
};
```

I have it so it outputs an embed, however it's always saying `[object, Promise]`

Comment: Slightly tangential, but it is **always** a bad idea to allow arbitrary, user-provided input to be evaluated as code. This likely opens a major security vulnerability for the server this code is running on.

Comment: I have a good enough understanding of js to configure it to be more secure, I just am unsure how to get that part down. That's why I'm asking about it, thanks though! I'm not sure if that's what you mean, but if so then yeah haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably guessed it, `[object, Promise]` means there's a promise here. The only solution is to `await` this Promise. I assume you could just make your function `async` and `await eval(result)`.